# NoReverseMatch at /13/download/ in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying to develop a small application using Django. Everything was working fine. Then, I added a "download" button to send mail to the user. Whenever I click on that button I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /13/download/
Reverse for 'about' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/about/$']
```

My views.py :

```
def download(request,pk):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request, 'set_goals/index.html')
else:
    user = request.user
    immediate = {}
    necessary = {}
    longterm = {}
    notnecessary = {}
    try:
        immediate = get_object_or_404(Immediate, user_id=pk)
        necessary = get_object_or_404(Necessary, user_id=pk)
        longterm = get_object_or_404(Longterm, user_id=pk)
        notnecessary = get_object_or_404(NotNecessary, user_id=pk)
    except:
        print("error somewhere")
    pdf = render_to_pdf('set_goals/all_goals.html',{'notnecessary':notnecessary,"immediate":immediate,"longterm":longterm,"necessary":necessary})
    if pdf:
        print("yes pdf")
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Goals.pdf"
        content = "inline; filename='%s'" % (filename)
        message = EmailMessage("Hello","These are your goals","8888888888@gmail.com",['999999999999999@gmail.com'])
        message.attach('mypdf.pdf',pdf,'application/pdf')
        message.send()
        return render(request,'set_goals/all_goals.html',{'notnecessary':notnecessary,"immediate":immediate,"longterm":longterm,"necessary":necessary})
    return render(request,'set_goals/index.html')
```

urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from . import views

app_name = 'set_goals'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/about/$',views.about,name='about'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/download/$', views.download, name='download'),
]
```

template :

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Immediate{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {% if immediate.body %}
                   <h2>{{immediate.title}}</h2>
                   <pre>{{immediate.body}}</pre>
                   {% else %}
                   <h2>Immediate Goals</h2>
                   <p>Yet to be placed!</p>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {% if necessary.body %}
                   <h2>{{ necessary.title }}</h2>
                   <pre>{{ necessary.body }}</pre>
                   {% else %}
                   <h2>Necessary Goals</h2>
                   <p>Yet to be placed!</p>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {% if longterm.body %}
                   <h2>{{ longterm.title }}</h2>
                   <pre>{{ longterm.body }}</pre>
                   {% else %}
                   <h2>Longterm Goals</h2>
                   <p>Yet to be placed!</p>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {% if notnecessary.body %}
                   <h2>{{ notnecessary.title }}</h2>
                   <pre>{{ notnecessary.body }}</pre>
                   {% else %}
                   <h2>Not Necessary Goals</h2>
                   <p>Yet to be placed!</p>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <a href="{% url 'set_goals:download' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Download &rarr;</a>
           </div>
       </div>
    {% else %}
        <h2>Please Login First</h2>
    {% endif%}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

download.html :

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Immediate{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {% if immediate.body %}
                   <h2>{{immediate.title}}</h2>
                   <pre>{{immediate.body}}</pre>
                   {% else %}
                   <h2>Immediate Goals</h2>
                   <p>Yet to be placed!</p>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {% if necessary.body %}
                   <h2>{{ necessary.title }}</h2>
                   <pre>{{ necessary.body }}</pre>
                   {% else %}
                   <h2>Necessary Goals</h2>
                   <p>Yet to be placed!</p>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {% if longterm.body %}
                   <h2>{{ longterm.title }}</h2>
                   <pre>{{ longterm.body }}</pre>
                   {% else %}
                   <h2>Longterm Goals</h2>
                   <p>Yet to be placed!</p>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {% if notnecessary.body %}
                   <h2>{{ notnecessary.title }}</h2>
                   <pre>{{ notnecessary.body }}</pre>
                   {% else %}
                   <h2>Not Necessary Goals</h2>
                   <p>Yet to be placed!</p>
                   {% endif %}
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    {% else %}
        <h2>Please Login First</h2>
    {% endif%}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When I click on the download button, then I am getting the above error. What is the mistake here? How to rectify it? I am newbie. Please help me. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Ok, the problem is probably related to a `{% url 'about' ...` tag, which can't be seen in your `download.html`. It _could be_ in your `base.html`. Look for that template tag.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Reverse for 'something' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['some path']
```

usually this error will be occurred when there is any mistake in template tags in the rendering template.

django will check all template tags before it renders, if there is any mismatch or incorrect in template tags.it will rise this exception.

```
 In download.html there is no about tag may it will be in base.html.check may be it is in correct or update question with base.thml
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment.